# Remote Javascript File, reference in PartialViewModel, not loading in Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, model-view-controller, firefox

I have a PartialViewModel in my MVC application that contains the following set up:

```
@model MyModel

<script type="text/javascript" src="PathToThirdPartyJSFile"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" language="javascript">

   //Use Function in ThirdPartyJS File.

</script>
```

This partial view model gets inserted into the `@section PageJavaScriptBottom` on a few different pages.  The javascript file is not referenced locally due to vendor request.

Using Firefox 9.0.1, this remote Javascript file does not get called/loaded for my session only and in Firefox only.  The file loads fine in IE, Chrome and Safari.  Firebug provides no insight.  Fiddler in Firefox shows that the request doesn't even get made.  I've cleared cache, cookies and everything else I can think of.  I can navigate to the remote JS file directly in Firefox with no issue.

Other folks in my office cannot reproduce this issue on their machines with Firefox 9.0.1.

What are some other diagnostics things that I can do to try and figure out what this issue is?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Firefox and Reinstalling? Seems kinda harsh, but it seems everyone else in your office is working fine, so I would suspect it's something with your machine's installation.

Comment: Not sure if it is related or if it's just a typo in the example, but this row looks a bit weird: `<script type = type="text/javascript" language="javascript">`. You write the type-attribute twice.

Comment: what is the relative path to the 3rd party PathToThirdPartyJSFile if it's in a different http:// location then put the fully qualified path..

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson That was a Typo, thanks.

Comment: @DJKRAZE The actual code contains the full, https path to the vendor's server. (http vs https makes no difference as well.)

Comment: have you tried using Fidler..? also if other users don't have the issues could it be something specific to the machine that you are working on or using..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Fiddler and Firebug don't expose anything, as I mention in my question.  The crux of my question is for additional diagnostic ideas to try and track this issue down.  I don't want to just chalk it up to gremlins as we have hundreds of thousands of users, some of whom may have the same configuration as I do.

Comment: there has to be a way to get at this while debugging .. not sure how from this end.. sorry I couldn't be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The host URL for the Vendor's Javascript File is listed in the AdBlock filter list I was using in my Firefox installation.